# Apply diesel filters to either single table or join?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm generating Diesel filters at runtime (using a similar approach to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291037/how-do-i-conditionally-order-by-a-column-based-on-a-dynamic-parameter-with-diese)). I have a function `make_filters` which generates filters for the table `tunnel`:

```rust
fn make_filters() -> Vec<Box<dyn BoxableExpression<tunnel::table, Pg, SqlType = Bool>>>
```

I'd like these filters to be applied to either the table `tunnel` or to the join of `tunnel` and `connection`. Like this:

```rust
let mut query = tunnel::table.left_join(connection::table).into_boxed();

for filter in filters.as_sql_where() {
    query = query.filter(filter);
}
```

But when I try, I get this error:

```
^^^ the trait 
`diesel::AppearsOnTable<diesel::query_source::joins::JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<tunnel::table, connection::table, diesel::query_source::joins::LeftOuter>, diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<connection::columns::tunnel_id>, diesel::expression::nullable::Nullable<tunnel::columns::id>>>>` 

is not implemented for `dyn diesel::BoxableExpression<tunnel::table, diesel::pg::Pg, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>`
```

This works fine if query is just `tunnel::table.into_boxed()`, so I think I need to generalize the typesignature of `make_filters`.

Minimal example [here](https://github.com/adamchalmers/diesel_left_joins/blob/master/src/main.rs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the filters can be applied to both, the joined tables and the `tunnel` table the preferred solution here is to just apply the filters before joining the tables. So something like this should work fine:

```rust
let mut query = tunnel::table.into_boxed();

for filter in filters.as_sql_where() {
    query = query.filter(filter);
}

let query = query.left_join(connection::table);
```