# Possible to genericize a boxed filter to be applied to either a single table or any query set where that table is present?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

How can a generic boxed filter be applied to a queryset that contains a table and every other queryset where the table is present?

For the following toy example, is there a way to make `get_filter` return something that may be applied to any queryset that has a `Foo` table present

```rust
use diesel::*;
use diesel::expression::*;
use std::boxed::Box;

type DB = diesel::pg::Pg;

diesel::table! {
    Foo (id) {
        id -> Int4,
    }
}

diesel::table! {
    Bar (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        foo_id -> Int4,
    }
}

diesel::allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    Foo,
    Bar,
);

pub fn get_queryset<'a>() -> Foo::BoxedQuery<'a, DB> {
    Foo::table.into_boxed()
}

use diesel::helper_types::*;
type QuerySetJoinType<'a> = IntoBoxed<
    'a,
    Filter<                                     
        InnerJoinOn<Foo::table, Bar::table, Eq<Bar::foo_id, Foo::id>>,
        Eq<Bar::id, diesel::expression::SqlLiteral<diesel::sql_types::Integer>>
    >,
    DB
>;

pub fn get_queryset_with_join<'a>() -> QuerySetJoinType<'a> {
    Foo::table
        .inner_join(Bar::table.on(Bar::foo_id.eq(Foo::id)))
        .filter(Bar::id.eq(42))
        .into_boxed()
}

type FilterReturnType = Box<dyn BoxableExpression<Foo::table, DB, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>>;

pub fn get_filter<'a>() -> FilterReturnType {
    let mut result : FilterReturnType = Box::new(Foo::id.eq(Foo::id));
    result = Box::new(result.and(Foo::id.gt(42)));
    result
}


fn main() {
    get_queryset().filter(get_filter());
    
    get_queryset_with_join().filter(get_filter());
}
```

This complains

```bash
   |
58 |     get_queryset_with_join().filter(get_filter());
   |                              ^^^^^^ the trait `AppearsOnTable<JoinOn<query_source::joins::Join<Foo::table, Bar::table, Inner>, diesel::expression::grouped::Grouped<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<Bar::columns::foo_id, Foo::columns::id>>>>` is not implemented for `dyn diesel::BoxableExpression<Foo::table, Pg, SqlType = Bool>`
```

I think I could maybe get there by parameterizing the query set like:

```rust
pub fn get_filter<'a, QS>() -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QS, DB, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>> {
    let mut result : Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QS, DB, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>> 
        = Box::new(Foo::id.eq(Foo::id));
    result = Box::new(result.and(Foo::id.gt(42)));
    result
}
```

But I'm stuck at which trait bounds need to be set on `QS`?

Any ideas how to get either path to work?

*This question **is** similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140096/apply-diesel-filters-to-either-single-table-or-join), except I actually want the types for the functions, and we're now on version 2 of diesel*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@weiznich provided guidance on [gitter.im/diesel-rs/diesel](https://gitter.im/diesel-rs/diesel) to make the query function generic as:

```rust
pub fn get_filter<'a, QS>() -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QS, DB, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>>
where
    QS: 'static,
    dsl::Eq<Foo::id, Foo::id>: BoxableExpression<QS, DB>,
    dsl::Gt<Foo::id, i32>: BoxableExpression<QS, DB>,
    dsl::AssumeNotNull<dsl::Eq<Foo::label, String>>: BoxableExpression<QS, DB>,
{
    let mut result : Box<dyn BoxableExpression<QS, DB, SqlType = diesel::sql_types::Bool>>
        = Box::new(Foo::id.eq(Foo::id));
    result = Box::new(result.and(Foo::id.gt(42)));
    let s = "asdf".to_string();
    result = Box::new(result.and(
        Foo::label.eq(s).assume_not_null()));
    result
}
```

Comment: Bread crumbs for others.  If compile is failing on something like `dsl::Gt<Foo::id, i32>: BoxableExpression<QS, DB>,` and the field you're filtering against is `left_join`'d, you may need to add `helper_types::AssumeNotNull` like `dsl::Gt<helper_types::AssumeNotNull<Foo::id>, i32>: BoxableExpression<QS, DB>,` and `Foo_::id.assume_not_null()`